# How are you supposed to differentiate $f(a) = (ax^2 + bx^3 + cx^4)^5$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(a) = (ax^2 + bx^3 + cx^4)^5$, how do you find $f'(a)$?  Assuming $x$ is independent of $a$, would $f'(a)$ just be $1$?

Comment: No, the question on the book states f(a). I could be wrong in that a is not a constant. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

As written, via the chain rule:
$$  f'(a) = 5(a x^2 + b x^3 + c x^4)^4 \cdot x^2  \text{,}  $$
but I seriously doubt this is what you were asked.

Alternatively, if this comes from an instructor, the instructor has noticed that the students are sloppy with their notation and has decided to point this out very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule I believe. With $u = ax^2 + bx^3 + cx^4$.

Differentiate $u$ wrt $a$, differentiate $y = u^5$ wrt $u$. And get your chain rule on.

$f'(a) = \frac{dy}{da} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{da}$